# Ubuntu 20.04.1 installer gets stuck at update and other software

Tags: system-installation, asus

I have an Asus X541U (i3 6006U, Intel graphics 520, 4 GB of RAM.)

When I plug in the USB and start to install Ubuntu `20.04.1` for the first time, it gets stuck on update and other software, even though I didn't click on install updates. I tried different USBs, different ports and nothing works.

In the bios I disabled fastboot. When trying Ubuntu I get PCIe bus error.

Comment: have you tried to install in offline mode as in no cable or wifi connection.

Comment: Yeah thats what I do it just get stuck loading

Comment: Please mention in your question which Ubuntu version you are trying to install. (Use the [edit] feature)

Comment: is there any problems when you try ubuntu,have you changed anything in bios/uefi,please edit the additional information into your question.

Comment: I did edit guys

Answer (score 0):

Solved by adding `pci=nomsi` in boot parameters.